# href scroll anchor angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

Im having a problem using href/anchor scrolling with angularjs. Once I click the h ref link it always links to the index page sample like this http://xxxxxx/#!/index#sec-menu not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for the assistance.

HTML

```
<div class="nav-holder main-menu">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#sec-menu">Menu</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<span class="fw-separator" id="sec-menu"></span>
```

not sure if this is the cause but I have something like this in my app.js

```
.otherwise({
  redirectTo: '/index'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="nav-holder main-menu">
  <nav>
     <ul>
        <li>
            <a ng-href="#/?scroll=sec-menu">My element</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
 <span class="fw-separator" id="sec-menu"></span>
```

change the run code in the module declaration in app.js like so:

```
app.run(function($location, $rootScope) {
 $rootScope.$watch(function() { return $location.search() }, function(search) {
 var po= 0;
 if (search.hasOwnProperty('scroll')) {
   var $target = $('#' + search.scroll);
   po= $target.offset().top;
   }
 $("body,html").animate({scrollTop: po}, "slow");
 });
})
```

Comment: Hi, Tried the code above but once I clicked it displayed http://xxxxxxx/#!/index#%2F%3Fscroll=sec-menu

Comment: @user799451 This link did not open! for me